# In the rocket equation, does lowering the acceleration due to gravity increase decrease exhaust velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, rocket-science, propulsion

I'm doing work for an intro space flight class, and I have to calculate the amount of fuel I need to get sizable a space craft, around 200 thousand kg in dry mass, into a transfer orbit from the surface of Mars.

Problem is, when I plug it into the rocket equation, I get a requirements of 900 BILLION KG OF FUEL. Am I missing something here?

The thing that confuses me is that apparently lowering the acceleration due to gravity lowers the exhaust velocity, thereby increasing the fuel needed. Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

> The thing that confuses me is that apparently lowering the acceleration due to gravity lowers the exhaust velocity, thereby increasing the fuel needed. Is this true?

No, that is not true. The exhaust velocity is determined by the engine design and the fuel used. It does not depend on the acceleration due to gravity. If it did then rockets would have 0 exhaust velocity in 0 g and therefore be unable to maneuver in 0 g.

Comment: But Ve is Isp x g

Comment: In that equation g is the constant 9.8 m/s^2. It is not the local gravitational field. Again, see the reasoning in my answer for a clear explanation why it cannot possibly be the local gravitational field.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks.